# Distance calcultation between array of strings for Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to make a recommendation system for suggesting friends to a user based on his/her interests ( a college project).
I have prepared the dataset(csv files) of user details and user interests :
They are in format :

```
"abcd","pqr","abcd@xyz.com","adf332" //userDetail
"Henry","Clifford","henrycliffordhenry.clifford@gzcz.com","sa1xVP" //userDetail
```

In another file :

```
"Henry","Clifford","Painting Photography EDM Algorithms Squash Graffiti Folk-music Badminton" //User interests
```

Now I want to to cluster the users on the basis of similarity between their interests.
I want to do it in such a way that the whole interest string is compared to another user not individually (that would take a lot of time ).
I have data for about 1,700,000 users.
I am stuck on calculating a distance matrix for the users that I could use in the clustering algos.

I tried Levenshtein distance but that wouldn't work as if the interests array `[ a,b,c,d]` would not be equal to   `[c,d,b,a]`

Also I am confused on which algo is best for this purpose ( k-means , fuzzy-cmeans or an hierarchical algorithm ).

I want the output to be cluster of users such that their interest arrays matches.

I couldn't find satisfactory results on web even after a lot of searching.

Any ideas on how to make the distance matrix for such string arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't work on the raw data.

Extract features, e.g. using the bag of words vectorspace model, and TF-IDF weighting.